# css рисует белые места в виджете

Tags: linux, c, gtk, gtk3, gtk+

есть такой код.

```
static gboolean main_frame_draw_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data ) {
        cairo_set_source_rgb ( cr, 0x3c / 255.0, 0x3c / 255.0, 0x3c / 255.0 );
        cairo_paint ( cr );
        return FALSE;
}

static gboolean text_view_draw_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data ) {
        cairo_set_source_rgb ( cr, 0x3c / 255.0, 0x3c / 255.0, 0x3c / 255.0 );
        cairo_paint ( cr );
        return FALSE;
}

const char *style = "textview text { background-color: #9c9c9c; outline-color: #3c3c3c; border-radius: 6px; }";

static gboolean entry_input_text_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data ) {
        GdkEventKey *key = ( GdkEventKey * ) event;
        if ( key->keyval == GDK_KEY_Return ) {
                const char *t = gtk_entry_get_text ( ( GtkEntry * ) entry_input_text );
                if ( strlen ( t ) == 0 ) return FALSE;

                GtkTextBuffer *buf = gtk_text_buffer_new ( NULL );
                gtk_text_buffer_set_text ( buf, t, strlen ( t ) );
                printf ( "t: %s\n", t );

                GtkWidget *frame = gtk_frame_new ( "" );
                gtk_frame_set_shadow_type ( ( GtkFrame * ) frame, GTK_SHADOW_NONE );

                GtkWidget *text_view = gtk_text_view_new_with_buffer ( buf ); 
                gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( text_view, 10 );
                gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( text_view, 10 );
                g_signal_connect ( text_view, "draw", G_CALLBACK ( text_view_draw_cb ), NULL );
                gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) frame, text_view );
                gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) text_box, frame, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
                gtk_widget_show_all ( text_box );

        }

        return FALSE;
}
```

я рисую текст. и вон видите, там где должно быть закруглено, там рисуется белый цвет. как это исправить? Он должен рисовать закругленный виджет. Если рисовать на белом фоне, то всё нормально смотриться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так. установил в css такой стиль, но я не думаю что он правильный, ведь все виджеты теперь надо перерисовывать.

```
* {
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
}
```

Еще решил проблему с отступом у фрейма. если создавать фрейм по обычному `gtk_frame_new`, то он резервирует место для `border`. если нужно место без лишних пикселей, то лучше создавать так `g_object_new ( GTK_TYPE_FRAME, "shadow-type", GTK_SHADOW_NONE, NULL );`